# Replicate RDS-MySQL to a non-amazon host?

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-rds

I have a fairly large MySQL (5.1) database running in Amazon as an RDS instance.  I'm working on migrating it out of Amazon.  To do that smoothly I'd like to set up the new hardware as a read-only replica of the RDS instance.

I know RDS supports replication within RDS.  Is there any way to configure it to replicate to a host which is not in RDS?

Comment: Is all your data InnoDB ???

Comment: Let's say "yes, it's all in innodb" - close enough to true for this forum. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's now possible to replicate to external mysql slaves from RDS: http://www.ruempler.eu/2013/07/07/replicating-aws-rds-mysql-databases-to-external-slaves/

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Amazon has chosen to forbid this for now:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=46377&tstart=0

Comment: The end of the thread confirms that with 5.6 it is possible and points to this blog post: http://www.ruempler.eu/2013/07/07/replicating-aws-rds-mysql-databases-to-external-slaves/

Answer (score 3):

If you have the following scenario

- all your data is innodb
- you have binary logging enabled on RDS

you could create a user in RDS like this

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'leopd'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'repl_password';
```

If Amazon does not permit '%' for the host name, you will need a specfic public IP address

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'leopd'@'xxx.xx.xx.xxx';
```

Next, mysqldump the data out of RDS as a single transaction

```
mysqldump -u... -p... --single-transaction --master-data=1 --all-databases --routines --triggers > /root/MySQLData.sql
```

Run the CHANGE MASTER TO command using leopd@'xxx.xx.xx.xxxx' as the user (xxx.xx.xx.xxxx is the IP address of RDS)

```
CHANGE MASTER TO
master_host = 'xxx.xx.xx.xxxx',
master_port = 3306,
master_user = 'leopd',
master_passwowrd = 'repl_pass'
master_log_file='slsnbj',
master_log_pos=1;
```

Load the data into a new server. Don't worry about the master_log_file='slsnbj' and
 master_log_pos=1. Line 22 of the dump will have the correct log file and position.

Run START SLAVE; on the new server

It should start working. You may have to worry about firewall considerations.

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2012-03-23 17:11 EDT**

You only have one chance left. See if you can set that last privilege with this:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Repl_slave_priv = 'Y' WHERE user='root' AND host='%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Perhaps this is being blocked for users that have % in the host column of mysql.user.

You may need to create another user with a hard public IP as I suggested earlier

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE,REPLICATION CLIENT ON *.* TO 'leopd'@'xxx.xx.xx.xxx';
```

It is possible replication slaves in RDS must also be RDS as well.

Comment: When logged in as root, `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE` results in `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)`

Comment: Please run `SHOW GRANTS`. Do you have all privileges on *.* ?

Comment: This is running as the RDS root user, which has all the privileges that are possible: `GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <snip> WITH GRANT OPTION`.  Looks like Amazon just doesn't allow this.

Comment: Updated my answer based on your last comment...

Comment: Did this method work?

Comment: @Radek the original poster (OP) answered it back on March 23rd : http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15492/877